# code coverage shows zero percentage - SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We are using SonarQube 6.4

Code coverage for both front end code(JavaScript) & back end code(java) shows 0%

[image]

[image]

Developers claim they have unit test cases for every function or class they write

This application has database layer

What does code coverage 0% mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/) sonarqube does **not** run tests, it simply imports report generated by other tools to display them along the other analysis.

So my guess is that you have not configured your CI chain to generate test reports to be shown in sonarqube.

Comment: I see test reports are in Jenkins workspace. Do I need to configure jenkins to show the test reports to show in Sonarqube? If yes, how

Comment: @overexchange i am not familiar with javascript or jenkins, however if you have the test reports generated by jacoco (java) and lcov (js) and thos reports are in the folder analyzed by sonar-scanner then you just need to add the properties sonar.jacoco.reportPaths and sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths in the sonar.properties configuration file indicating where to find those files.

Comment: Is sonar.properties configuration file an input to sonar sonar scanner only? Does sonar scanner forward the reports to sonar Qube server?

Comment: @overexchange yes and yes, however these questions are really in the first lines of the sonarqube documentation...

Comment: If you are running the tests in the docker and sonar runs on the host machine, here is the fix - http://www.tundriyal.com/sonarqube-fixing-sonar-code-coverage-zero-percentage-issue

Comment: was able to generate coverage with jacoco and passing theses properties to https://medium.com/backend-habit/generate-codecoverage-report-with-jacoco-and-sonarqube-ed15c4045885                                                                    `sonnarscanner sonar.projectKey=b
sonar.sources=
sonar.java.binaries=
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.language=java
sonar.junit.reportsPath=xxx/target/surefire-reports
sonar.surefire.reportsPath=xxx/target/surefire-reports
sonar.verbose=true
sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=xxx/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco`